# Marionette.js: Rendering a different view for one model in a collection

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a collection of models.
I want to render the same view for all the models in that collection, except for one for which the view should be unique.

Normally, I would use a CollectionView to render the same ItemView for the whole collection, but that won't work in my case.

The options I've thought of are:

1. Use the same ItemView for all models, but have some logic in it that renders something different for that specific model.
2. Use a CompositeView which gets the collection without the unique model, and gets that unique model as its model. Then render the collection one way, and the model some other way.

Which option is better? Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar-ish use case with a nested set of collections. I'm using CompositeView to recursively render all the nodes of the tree, each of which might need a slightly different template. By using the `getTemplate` method I can inspect the model and use one of several different templates. Pretty much what @David outlined, but here's an example:

```
getTemplate: function(){
  var template;
  switch (this.model.get('type')) {
    case 'film':
      template = 'film';
      break;
    case 'item':
      template = 'item';
      break;
    case 'year':
    case 'decade':
      template = 'node';
      break;
  }
  return template;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with your second idea: use a composite view that receives the "special model" and a collection.

But if you have one model that needs to be treated differently, you might want to reconsider your data structure. It seems like an unusual setup, but maybe there's a better way to approach the problem.

Comment: I have a list of 10 options the user can choose from. 9 of them set some predefined values, and 1 needs user input for those values. So 9 out of 10 need to be displayed as radio buttons, and 1 as a radio button with additional input fields. 
I've defined the options as a collection of models. Do you see something I can change in my data structure?

Comment: You should be able to determine if the option requires user input from inspecting the model. If that's the case, just check for that in the template, and use the same template for all the option models. Have you tried that approach?

Comment: Our approach is to have logic-less templates. We encapsulate all our logic in our View. But, if I get your meaning, I should have the option model know whether or not it requires user input, and have the ItemView show something else for model instances that say they need user input?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm all for templates without logic, but for me inspecting a model attribute to adapt template display is a valid approach. Otherwise, you'll end up writing a lot of code elsewhere... For example, filtering the collection to separate options that require user input from those that don't... (And possibly writing new views/templates with duplicated code.)